# Calling External/third-party URL via feignclient works, but results in warnings

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I am trying to use feignclient to call a third party url (sending notifications to android devices)

```
@FeignClient(value = "external",url = "${android.notification.url}")
public interface AndroidNotificationClient {

    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    String sendAndroidNotification(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String auth, @RequestHeader ("Sender") String sender,
                                                 @RequestBody String body);

}
```

"external" is not defined anywhere - I was told that value is not used for any purponse.

The API calls work, but I get warnings like

```
2022-05-10 07:52:17.015 WARN  --- [boundedElastic-1]  org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer         : No servers available for service: fcm.googleapis.com
2022-05-10 07:52:17.016 WARN  --- [androidNotification8]  org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient         : Service instance was not resolved, executing the original request
```

The relevant portion of the properties file is reproduced below

```
feign.client.url=http://<our_domain_name>/api
android.notification.url=https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
android.authorization=key=xxxx
android.sender=id=xxxxx



eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://<our_domain_name>:<port>/eureka}
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```

What am I doing wrong which is resulting in such warnings, and how do I remove them?

Comment: This was a know issue in OpenFeign and was fixed in version 2.2.8. (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/508). What version do you use?

Comment: I found the known issue independently. However, I am not using Openfeign, and am using org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign. I got this error with version 3.0.0. I have checked till 3.0.3, and the code appears to be the same. Has it not been fixed in spring-cloud-openfeign? Should I try to exclude from spring-cloud-starter  or use openfeign directly?

Comment: Update: Changed the loglevel of RoundRobinLoadBalancer and FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient to Error. Supressing the warns was important  for as as monitoring tools pick up warn and error messages.