# Using @FeignClient by URL attribute to call external rest API does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have a microservice and want to call a rest API thanks to FeignClient. I have used this:

```
@FeignClient( url = "${sample.url}")
```

But it doesn't work.

When I run my application, I get error:

> Either 'name' or 'value' must be provided in @FeignClient

note that it is not a service which is registered in Eureka, It's an external rest API. I have added a sample name, then I got error `Service id not legal hostname`. My spring boot version is 2.7.3. It's ok for calling API from another microservice which is registered in Eureka.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72182787/839733

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot REST service exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902374/spring-boot-rest-service-exception-handling)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Nope

Comment: @Hicomputer Nope

Comment: Are you sure? Because how to call an external service using Feign is well-documented. The post I linked to also shows how to do it.

Comment: I have commented on kerbermeister's post. The problem was the pattern of name attribute. @AbhijitSarkar

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of `FeignClient` for `value()`:

```java
/**
 * The name of the service with optional protocol prefix. Synonym for {@link #name()
 * name}. A name must be specified for all clients, whether or not a url is provided.
 * Can be specified as property key, eg: ${propertyKey}.
 * @return the name of the service with optional protocol prefix
 */
@AliasFor("name")
String value() default "";
```

and `name()` :

```java
/**
 * @return The service id with optional protocol prefix. Synonym for {@link #value()
 * value}.
 */
@AliasFor("value")
String name() default "";
```

So along with `url` you should provide either a `name` or `value` for your feign client

Also, if you get an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service id not legal hostname` while using feign client, the cause may be is that feign client does not accept service name with under score. Just check this. The rules for naming are not documented, this point is just from my experience.

Also, you can read the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults) where pointed:

> Previously, using the url attribute, did not require the name
> attribute. Using name is now required.

Comment: I thought it related to services that are registered in eureka. the Name will process and should follow the format that is acceptable for the URL. I have checked the URL class in Java and the getName method in feign.

Comment: so, you're still facing the problem?

Comment: It is solved. @kerbermeister

Comment: so upvote, accept the answer if it has solved your problem, or provide your solution that helped you, so that community would know how to solve this kind of problem if someone faced the same

Comment: plz, describe in your answer that name property should follow which pattern.   "not accepting service name with underscore" is not enough. but it's a good hint. then I will accept your answer. Thanks. @kerbermeister

Comment: @HamidFarid actually it is not documented, it is just from my experince. I edited my answer